# How to fix controller error in Ruby on Rails and get Paperclip up and running, fix params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have been trying for quite a while to get Paperclip up and running on my website and have followed the step-by-step process outlined on github multiple times and it still won't work. I really need to get this up and running as soon as possible. When I run the code through localhost, I get the message, "param is missing or the value is empty: survey." I thought I'd defined both surveys and their parameters here:

---

`

```
class SurveysController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :new, :create, :survey_params, :owners, :seeker, :survey_params, :idcheck,
    def new
        @survey = Survey.new
    end

    def create
    end

     def survey_params
        params.require(:survey).permit(:survey, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :looking_for, :moving_to, :gender, :coed, :age, :roommate_type, :housing_type, :roommates_estimate, :roommates_amount, :roommates_group, :roommates_names, :max_rent, :move_in, :move_out, :bedrooms, :amenities, :apartment_pet, :roommate_pet, :hometown, :school, :company, :terms, :avatar, :wake_up, :bedtime, :smoke, :smokeoften, :smokesocially, :smokequit, :drink, :drinkoften, :drinksocially, :drinkquit, :drugs, :drugsoften, :drugssocially, :drugsquit, :interest, :sexualactivity, :sexprivacy, :roommatesexprivacy, :overnight, :overnightoften, :roommateovernight, :realty, :availability, :rent, :address, :otherroom, :age_min, :age_max, :age_mode, :pad_photo, :user_status, :sociability, :tidiness, :question, :noise, :political, :religion, :user_id)
    end

    def owners
        @survey = Survey.new(survey_params)
        @survey.user_id=current_user.id
        @survey.save
    end
    def seeker
        @survey = Survey.new
        @survey.save
    end

private

    def idcheck

    end

end
```

`

---

Also here is my survey class: (app/models/survey.rb)

---

```
    class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :small => "150x150>" },
                        :url => "/assets/surveys/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                        :path => ":rails_root/public//assets/surveys/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

    validates_attachment_presence :avatar
    validates_attachment_size :avatar, :less_than => 5.megabytes
    validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']
end
```

---

...and here's where I've tried to include the photo uploader (views/surveys/seeker.html.erb)

---

```
    <p>
                                        <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
                                    </p>
                                    <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>

            <!---</div>-->
            <div class="circle_wrapper roommates_both">
                <div class="dark_circle" ></div>
                <div class="light_circle" ></div>
                <div class="light_circle" ></div>
            </div>

            <div class="housing_only">
                <div class="submit_button">
                <input id="submit_room_only" class="nextbutton one pages submitbutton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit!" disabled/>
                </div>
        </div>
        </form>

<% end %>
        <form action="FileUpload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="upload">Upload your Profile Photo:</label><br />
    <input type="file" name="upload" id="upload"><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
    <div class="roommates_both">
                <input id="next1" class="nextbutton one pages" type="submit" name="submit" value="Save and continue >"/>
            </div>
</form>
 <!-- End of page one -->
         </div>
    </div> <!-- End of wrapper -->
```

---

What do I need to fix here for it to work? Here is the my website.

https://github.com/chawalk90/padibilityweb

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your survey controller. This should solve the issue.

```
def create
  @survey = Survey.new(survey_params)
end

private
    def survey_params
        survey_params = params.require(:survey).permit(:avatar)
    end
```

Comment: thank you, I tried this, but I'm still having problems

Comment: I was looking through your rails app in your github and i saw that you are trying to run two migration to add an avatar to users. In your first migration to add an avatar you had a misplaced "end".Double check your work and try keep everything clean.